# I have an Beacon device and i would like to make an app

Tags: android

I have an ibeacon device and i would like to make and android app which shows that all the smartphone on listview connected or capture by the beacon on my app. How could i make such app any suggestions.

Comment: need more clarity

Comment: i want to make an android app which shows the list of android smartphone nearby beacon i.e the smartphone that are capture by beacon device. i want to detect all the smartphone with my app using the beacon.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the android ble scanner.

check for the link [Ble documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)

see what is the iBeacon [what is iBeacon](http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/what-is-iBeacon.html)

Actually a Beacon have 4 parts

1. UUID (16 byte)
2. Major (2 byte)
3. Minor (2 byte)
4. Prefix (4 byte)

And the only difference between iBeacon and beacon is the **prefix**.

So filter the prefix for iBeacon. And you have a unique UUID filter it out and calculate the rssi,

done

Comment: i am using for the first time could you explain me in details i see the documentation and i got the problem on
 private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
could you express this with the code. #Godwin